# Epic Android phone not seen by my computer when I plug it in

Tags: windows-7, usb, 64-bit, android

Usually, when I plug my phone into a computer the phone sees the computer and puts up a prompt for Mass Storage mode, Tether, or charging.

I know the phone is ok because I have seen this using my work computer.

At home, no prompt comes up on the phone when I plug the phone into the computer.

My computer is Windows 7, 64bit.

Is there any way for me to diagnose the computer to find out how to fix it without a rebuild?

I just tried different ports: each time the phone beeps and charges but no prompt.

Device Manager shows a bunch of USB devices, no errors.

https://picasaweb.google.com/Decker97/ComputerDiag?authuser=0&feat=directlink

Comment: Does the phone charge when plugged in? Have you tried multiple ports?

Comment: I second MaQleod to try different ports. IF neither of the ports work then I would suggest Computer/Manage/Device Manager and see if you can see anything there. IF not try looking into drivers from phone's site.

Comment: I now suspect the cable - Monday I will try the cable from work that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

http://androidforums.com/epic-4g-support-troubleshooting/163937-help-my-computer-doesnt-recognize-epic-how-mount-drivers-dont-freak-out.html

Comment: There's also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12793/my-samsung-galaxy-s-doesnt-recognize-when-it-is-plugged-in-to-usb and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9249/tmobile-my-touch-3g-htc-magic-doesnt-give-option-to-mount-usb-storage-anymore and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6363/usb-mass-storage-not-working and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6358/why-doesnt-my-samsung-galaxy-s-communicate-via-usb and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6211/cant-see-nexus-one-as-a-usb-drive-when-connecting-to-windows-7 ...

Comment: Turns out it was the cable.

Comment: Same problem, same solution. Turns out some cables will charge, but allow the transfer of data.